# How to offset NSDate with UTC timezone offset without hardcoded manual calculation

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Imagine the current local time being `15:11` UTC. I retrieve a data set from the server showing the opening closing time of a business displayed like so:

```
{
close = {
   day = 3;
   time = 0200;
};
open = {
   day = 2;
   time = 1700;
};
```

I also receive a utc-offset property exposed like so: `"utc_offset" = "-420”;` which I imagine is a minute offset giving an hour offset of 7 hours which seems right considering the timezone I'm in is UTC and the business location's opening hours information I'm receiving is for a business in Los Angeles who are 7 hours behind.

How do I use this property to then be able to do any time calculations on it
I want to determine whether the current local time falls between the open and close time that bit I have figured out but the calculations come out wrong considering the time comparison is done in the local timezone when it needs to be offset before calculating against that time range.

I'm trying to avoid doing things like

Psuedocode:
`NSDate.date hour componenent + (UTC_offset / 60 = -7 hours)`

**Update:**
Here's how I'm currently checking if the business is open right now

```
        if currentArmyTime.compare(String(openInfo.time)) != .OrderedAscending && currentArmyTime.compare(String(closeInfo.time)) != .OrderedDescending {
            //The business is open right now, though this will not take into consideration the business's time zone offset.
        }
```

Is it easier to offset the current time?

Comment: Use NSDateFormatter to parse the time, including the timezone

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want. It is hard to imagine you actually have UTC as the local time, more likely you are in BST? Do you want to convert between BST and PDT? Or is this just about parsing? Did you read the relevant Apple docs on [calendar calculations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1)?

Comment: If you are UTC, LA is 8 hours behind.  Just sayin'.

Comment: I think you guys are right, I might have quoted the wrong time zone the device is in.

Comment: @hnh so as the question reads, I want to render a time is offset by the integer value given. Damn it, I could have possibly condensed the whole question down with this statement alone. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can use the 'open' and 'close' times in date operations you need to create an NSDate from a calendar that has been set to the time zone for those times.   Here's an example:

```
// Create calendar for the time zone
NSInteger timeOffsetInSeconds = -420 * 60;
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:timeOffsetInSeconds];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
calendar.timeZone = tz;

// Create an NSDate from your source data
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.day = 1;
comps.month = 1;
comps.year = 2016;
comps.hour = 8;
comps.minute = 0;
NSDate *openTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

// 'openTime' can now be to compared with local time.
NSLog(@"openTime = %@", openTime);  // Result is openTime = 2016-01-01 15:00:00 +0000
```

You should put the above code into a method that takes in the raw time and the time offset to apply.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Could you check the update to my question please?

Comment: I'm still struggling to figure out how to get a current NSDate object and adding that offset.

Comment: I think you need to consider the local date as well, in addition to the time.   In your sample data, the opening (5pm) and closing (2am) times span *two days*.   That's probably what the `day` field is for.   Is there any way, from your source data, to determine all the date components, i.e., year and month in addition to the day and time?    Once you have all the date components, create the opening and closing NSDates using the method shown in the answer.   You can then use native date operations on those NSDates without having to worry about timezones.