# How to convert milliseconds to UTC time in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, timezone, nsdate

I am getting milliseconds time from backend guys. I have to convert that into UTC time zone because then I can convert that to any time zone easily.
Or there is any way to change time according to country with out changing to UTC time zone.

I am using this code

```
  NSDate *currentDate = mydate;
        double secsUtc1970 = [currentDate timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:secsUtc1970];


NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
         NSTimeZone *inputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
        [format setTimeZone:inputTimeZone];
            [format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
            [format setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        NSLog(@"%@",[format stringFromDate:date]);


            NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
            NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [outputDateFormatter setTimeZone:outputTimeZone];
            [outputDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
            [outputDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
            NSString *outputString = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
            NSLog(@"%@",outputString);
```

my milliseconds are 1468930910629
thanks

Comment: your qustion is good, are your tried still morning onwards correct,

Comment: ok can you show your milli seconds

Comment: see my edited question

Answer (score 1):

Remember that [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithLocale:) is internally represented as some value relative to a **UTC** date in the past.    Having this fixed reference point makes NSDate timezone independent, allowing you to compare NSDates with NSDates without having to worry about timezones.

So, the key thing for everything else to work is to create NSDates properly.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38458270/4130118) or [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html) for examples.